# Sorting union result set of two table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, union

I have two tables which are totally different by field and data but I want sorted data from both the tables. I have use union clause for that purpose and I am successful to fetch the result set but unable to sort the data. I have tried so many tricks but fail.

My query is -

```
  (SELECT amount FROM `purchase` order by amount desc limit 0, 10 )
UNION
(SELECT total_price as amount from `item` order by total_price desc limit 0, 10) order by amount desc
```

the result is -

```
-----------   
amount
-----------
9999.000
9998.000
999.000
9730
7750
7700
7600
6881
20000
13400
10250
10000
```

The result is OK but you can see that data is not sort by amount, it is sorted by table. But I want highest at the top i.e 20000 and so on. Can anyone tell me what change I have to make in the query to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one of (or both) `amount` and `total_price` is text type. How about cast like this:

```
(SELECT amount + 0 AS amount FROM `purchase` order by amount desc limit 0, 10)
UNION
(SELECT total_price + 0 AS amount from `item` order by total_price desc limit 0, 10)
ORDER BY amount desc
```

If `xxx + 0` not working, use `CAST(total_price AS SIGNED INTEGER)`.

Comment: Before going onward, can you please explain me.? what is that + 0 is doing here and how it effect my data?  @ InoS Heo

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer It's common trick in MySQL (or PHP) which is not forcing strict data type. Using `CAST()` function is standard way to converting data type.

Comment: amount is varchar type and total_price is int type

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer `SELECT '1'` just returns string data, `SELECT '1' + 0` returns numeric data.

Comment: No, no, sorry @InoS Heo I was wrong. Your query is perfectly working. you are awesome. awesome trick.

Comment: @ThePlusProgrammer OK. Fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     ( 
            SELECT cast(amount AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as amount 
            FROM   `purchase` limit 0, 10 
            UNION 
            SELECT total_price AS amount 
            FROM   `item` limit 0, 10) a 
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

## [SAMPLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29b24c/1)

Comment: Sorry @Manwal Not done. all sort result is totlly miss matches

Comment: In very simple words a query to achieve this, some data from one table and some data from second table by limit clause, union that all data and sort result by highest value.

Comment: that sqlFiddle is working very fine but that same query is not working with my data, not showing proper result. don't know why.?

Comment: What is type of your `amount` and `total_price` column?

Comment: amount is varchar type and total_price is int type